# In process of image zooming, Sampling rate changes or stays constant?

Tags: image-processing, matlab

When we zoom an image, our sampling rate will be changed(increased) or sampling rate will not change because of zooming operation?

Comment: Do you mean when you *digitally* zoom an image, or when you *optically* zoom in a camera?

Comment: digitally zoom an image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it changes the sampling rate. Just like with audio, 1 kHz tone is 1 kHz tone after resampling from 48kHz to 96kHz. So the image has same content, but with more pixels.

Comment: so in nutshell?,you mean, number of pixels increase in zooming and also sampling rate increases in zooming?

Comment: If you have a picture that's X pixels per meter and you zoom it by a factor of two while retaining the same pixel count, it'll have 2X pixels per meter in the end -- so, twice the sampling rate.

Comment: you said "while retaining same pixel count" but still you changed "X" to "2X"?